# How do I use pcl_to_scan to convert PointCloud into LaserScan?

Tags: pcl, ros-groovy, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I need to use PointCloud library and convert the point cloud information into LaserScan so that it acts as  laser scanner. I found pcl_to_scan (google it) package, But don't know how to use it? Can anybody explain to me its usage? Any answers will be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68605/how-do-i-use-pcl_to_scan-to-convert-pointcloud-into-laserscan?/) by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-07-24**:
Please mention your ros distro.

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-07-31**:
Sorry about that. I'm using groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is another package **pointcloud_to_laserscan** which converts the 3D point cloud data to 2D laser scan data. It is in the **turtlebot** stack which can be installed using the following command (for fuerte and groovy):
**sudo apt-get install ros--turtlebot**

Then create a launch file as follows:

```
    <launch>
  <!-- kinect nodes -->
  <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>

  <!-- openni_manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="openni_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/>

  <!-- throttling -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager">
    <param name="max_rate" value="2"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

  <!-- fake laser -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager">
  <!--Setting the parameters for obtaining scan data within desired ranges-->
    <param name="max_height" value="0.30"/>
    <param name="min_height" value="-0.15"/>
    <param name="angle_min" value="-0.5233"/>
    <param name="angle_max" value="0.5233"/>
    <param name="range_min" value="0.50"/>
    <param name="range_max" value="6.0"/>
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>
```

The laser scan data is a linear array and is published as the topic **/scan**.

---

Originally posted by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) with karma: 156 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-07-31**:
I'm trying that, but I use a model with kinect, there is no openni yet. So, I need to manipulate this in order to use with the model with kinect. First thing that has came to mind was to disabling openni_manager, but that didn't work. Can you help me?

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-08-01**:
Please refer to my new question: /70360/using-pcl_to_scan-without-openni-to-convert-pointcloud-into-laserscan/

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-08-23**:
Nevertheless, close enough.